# Pandas: Get abs() mean() in Aggregate function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, dask, dask-dataframe

[From the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) it is possible to `.aggregate` a `dataframe.groupby` object like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],
                   [-4, 5, 6],
                   [7, 8, 9],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]],
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

and then `aggregate` like this:

```
my_agg = {'A' : ['mean', 'min'], 'B' : ['mean', 'max']}
df.agg(my_agg)
```

Thats nice, but I would like to take the `abs(np.mean)` of column `A` here. Is it possible to define it as part of `my_agg`? What would be a solution for dask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes we can pass `lambda`

```
my_agg = {'A' : ['mean', 'min', lambda x : abs(x.mean())], 'B' : ['mean', 'max']}
df.agg(my_agg)
Out[194]: 
                 A    B
<lambda>  1.333333  NaN
max            NaN  8.0
mean      1.333333  5.0
min      -4.000000  NaN
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfect for `pandas.DataFrame`. For `dask`, it yields `ValueError: unknown aggregate lambda`. So it looks like that `lambda` can not be used in this place.

Comment: @gies0r try with def your function ~ and agg with your function

Comment: Dask was not part of your original question. You could edit or ask anew.

Comment: @mdurant it was in it as a tag in the original question. I did a short update to also ask for dask.